# Add all elements from a table to another table in lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

In javascript you can do the following

```js
const obj1 = {a:1, b:'blue', c:true};
const obj2 = {...obj1, d:3, e:'something else'};
```

and you object 2 will have all of obj 1 in it.

Is there a way to do this in lua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to write your own function for this purpose:

```lua
local function add_missing(dst, src)
    for k, v in pairs(src) do
        if dst[k] == nil then
           dst[k] = v
        end
    end
    return dst -- for convenience (chaining)
end
```

which you may then use as follows:

```lua
local obj1 <const> = {a = 1, b = 'blue', c = true}
local obj2 <const> = add_missing({d = 3, e = 'something else'}, {a = 1, b = 'blue', c = true})
```

---

Note: JavaScript's spread operator also guarantees a certain order of execution; that is, in your example fields from `obj2` would override those from `obj1`, which is why I've included an explicit `nil` check to only include missing fields:

```js
> {...{a: 2}, a: 1}
{ a: 1 }
> {a: 1, ...{a: 2}}
{ a: 2 }
```